# Parse lines and save to different arrays after a matching pattern in a file

Tags: arrays, string, perl, split

Example file:

```
some texts....
....

FINAL RESULTS

....
some texts

Needed data:   -25.684   -61.647   -20.061            #need this line
               -61.647    82.482   -15.683            #need this line
               -20.061   -15.683   -56.799            #DOES NOT need this line
Needed data:   -24.557   -48.468     2.592            #need this line
               -48.468    62.053    -6.742            #need this line
               -2.592    -6.742   -37.495             #DOES NOT need this line
Needed data:   -42.875  -101.901   -30.377            #need this line
               -101.901   134.323   -24.259           #need this line
               -30.377   -24.259   -91.448            #DOES NOT need this line
```

I would like to search for "FINAL RESULTS", then search for "Needed data" and extract the numbers in the first and second line but not the third line, and put them into arrays.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    my $in_sec;
    open(IN, "< t.in") or die;
    while (<IN>)
    {
      if    (/FINAL RESULTS/)     { $in_sec = 1; }
      elsif (/(?<!FINAL RESULTS):/) { $in_sec = 0; }

      if ($in_sec) {
        if(/Needed data/) {
         @a = split;
         print "@a\n";
         if ($_ = <IN>) {
            @b = split;
            print "@b\n";
         }
      }
     }
    }
```

But nothing is printed.

Comment: I haven't write the part to assign the value to arrays yet. Try to figure out the first part first :-).

Comment: I used another input file with similar format and it worked ?  But I don't know how to put line break to the file ?

Comment: some text  \n
... \n
... \n
Foo:  \n
  var1 = 1  \n
  var2 = 2  \n
  var3 = 3  \n
Bar:  \n
  var1 = 4 \n
  var2 = 5 \n
  var3 = 6 \n
FINAL RESULTS \n
.....  \n
test  \n
  var1 = 7  \n
  var2 = 8  \n
  Needed data = 9 8 7 6 \n
         8 \n
  Needed data = 99 12 \n
 88 4   \n
  Needed data = 999  \n
    888  \n

Comment: @YuChen: If that's your expected output, please edit your question to add it in there :)

Answer (score 1):

With a Perl's one-liner:

```
perl -0nE '
    push @a, split for /(?<=Needed data:)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\N\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+/g;
    END{say join "\n", @a}
' t.in
```

As a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use File::Slurp;

my @a;
$_ = read_file($ARGV[0]);
push @a, split for /(?<=Needed data:)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\N\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+/g;
say join "\n", @a;
```

### Output

```
-25.684
-61.647
-20.061
-61.647
82.482
-15.683
-24.557
-48.468
2.592
-48.468
62.053
-6.742
-42.875
-101.901
-30.377
-101.901
134.323
-24.259
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(?<=` | [look behind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions) to see if there is: |
| `Needed` | data: 'Needed data:' |
| `)` | end of look-behind |
| `\s+` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\S+` | non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\s+` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\S+` | non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\s+` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\S+` | non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\N` | new line |
| `\s*` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\S+` | non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\s+` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\S+` | non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\s+` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\S+` | non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Answer (score 1):

Your `elsif` test matches the `:` in `Needed data:` line.

Without that test, your code would produce output.

---

Here's a method using `..` / `...` :

```
perl -nE '
    next if 1 .. /FINAL RESULTS/;

    if ( $n = /Needed data/ ... $. ) {
        s/#.*//;
        push @{ $n==1 ? \@a : \@b }, /-?\d+\.\d+/g;
    }

    END {
        say "\@a = @a";
        say "\@b = @b";
    }
' t.in
```

- skip to relevant line using `..` operator
- process "Needed data" and next line

  - `...` is like `..` but delays second test
  - `$.` is just used as a variable that is always positive
  - strip comments
  - extract everything that looks like a number
  - `push` to appropriate array
- display the stored arrays